# Fullcalendar: Showing wrong Date in Day's view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

When navigated to Day view in Full Calendar, date displayed is showing based on the System Timezone i.e Even though our application timezone is UTC+5:30, it is showing the Date based on my machine timezone (UTC-5:30).

I tried setting timezone='Asia/Kolkata' but still it is picking my machine timezone. Any suggestions on this issue?

[FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) Version - 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Try with setting local timezone as below

```
 timezone='local'
```